# show popup for one time on homepage magento

Tags: php, magento, session-cookies, setcookie, jquery-cookie

I want to show a popup on homepage which has two buttons (say bitton1 and button2) If button2 is clicked ones it should redirect to homepage and then should not open for atleast 2 days.

I had added the popup on my home page and onclick of button2 Iam using setcookie function:

```
function setCookie() {
    $.cookie('test_status', '1', { path: '/', expires: 60 });
    return false;
}
```

but it gives error : `TypeError: $.cookie is not a function`

For this I had added the below script :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
```

but still It gives the same error.

How can I achieve this task?

Comment: You can get idea or change extension as per your requirements with below extension.
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/newsletter-subscription-with-free-gift-coupon-popup.html

Comment: I had the popup coming on my home page. I just need to set cookie so that on button click it should redirect to homepage and never popup again for atleast 2 days

Comment: try using jQuery instead of $

Answer (score 0):

Dollar $ sign is created conflict with prototype.js so you can try to use or add Jquery conflict code and using like below. Hope this helps.

```
function setCookie() {
    jQuery.cookie('test_status', '1', { path: '/', expires: 60 });
    return false;
}
```